# SpriteKit detect if node is removed from parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Is there a method that gets called every time a node is deleted? or added?

Along the terms of `touchesBegan` a method that gets called every time a touch on the screen happens.

or `touchesMoved` a method that gets called when a node gets touched and moved.

So is there such a method that gets called when a node gets `removeFromParent`?

I am currently using the `update` method to detect if a node is still present like:

```
SKNode *n = [self childNodeWithName: @"n"];
if (!n)
{
    // no n
    if (life != 0)
    {
        [self addChild:_n);
        life--;
    }
}
```

Now when ever that node is missing I remove 1 life, and then add the node again.

The problem is the update method is running too fast that 2 lives are removed every time the node is removed. I believe this is because adding the node back is kinda slower that the update method. So it takes 2 loops on the update method before it detects that the node is present again.

Comment: how do you remove your node? you should call life--; in the method where you remove your node

Comment: I also remove it by detecting if it is out of the screen in the `update` method. If it is, then I do `removeFromParent` on it. I have tried that, and the same result happened.

Comment: what happens after you remove  the node? a new node appear right?

Comment: @JechtMontoya that is right. But it runs through update twice before the node even gets added again. It seems like the adding of the node takes time. and the update method is faster.

Comment: i post you my answer, sorry for the delay i'm at work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method. But you can create one.

Create a subclass of (for example) SKSpriteNode and override all "remove" methods (or just those you are using). Within that method send a message to whichever object needs to receive the removal event, or send a notification and register other objects to receive that notification. Don't forget to call the super implementation of the overridden method.

Comment: I will try to google how to create a subclass and override methods.
or can you point me to how?

Comment: I believe this is the class I have to override? [SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) am I right?

Comment: Nope, a subclass of SKNode with the overridden remove method will not be called if, for example, you're using a SKSpriteNode. You have to subclass the specific subclass you're using, not SKNode. You could however create a category on SKNode and add a special method, say 'removeFromParentWithNotification' that any SK*Node class would use if it is supposed to send a removal notification.

Comment: I am using `SKShapeNode`, I am trying to create a class that subclasses that now.

Comment: lastly how do I call my extended removeFromParent from my `MyShapeNode.m` to `MyScene.m`?

Answer (score 2):

if you run this lines inside update

```
SKNode *n = [self childNodeWithName: @"n"];
if (!n)
```

that statement will run forever until you stop the game or your node is not equal to nil

to correct that behaviour you need to create a **BOOL** value

```
BOOL _shouldProceed;
```

change the name if you want

when you create your node set **BOOL** value to true or yes

```
- (void)createNode {
    _shouldProceed = YES;

    // Your implementation for the node
}
```

and put this inside update

```
SKNode *n = [self childNodeWithName:@"n"];

if (!n && _shouldProceed) {
    _shouldProceed = NO;

    if (life != 0) {
        [self createNode];
         life--;
    }
}
```

if your node is equal to nil and **BOOL** value is equal to true/yes 
you need to set **BOOL** value to false/NO

with this approach this statement only will happens once

when you create a new node with

```
[self createNode];
```

the **BOOL** value is set to true/YES

and that should solve your problems

Good Luck!!

Comment: Up voted for a solution but this doesn't actually answer my question. but thanks :)